# Error while using npm install -g generator-jhipster

Tags: node.js, npm, jhipster

I am following the installation steps at https://jhipster.github.io/installation.html. Every thing went fine till generator-jhipster. When I run npm install -g generator-jhipster, I am getting the following errors, can any one help me to fix this?

```
C:\Users\smart>npm install -g generator-jhipster
/
> spawn-sync@1.0.13 postinstall C:\Users\smart\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\cross-spawn\node
_modules\spawn-sync
> node postinstall

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "generator-jhipster"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path C:\Users\smart\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\isarray\0.0.1\package\p
ackage.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048

npm ERR! Error: EPERM, rename 'C:\Users\smart\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\isarra
y\0.0.1\package\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, rename 'C:\Users\smart\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\is
array\0.0.1\package\package.json']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\smart\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\isarray\\0.0.
1\\package\\package.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 'readable-stream' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\smart\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Please try running this command again as root/Administrator`

Have you actually tried it?

Comment: That is the key which I ignored as others were installed without root

Comment: @smart987 Please mark it as solved if it works for you

Comment: You should not need to install as admin and it's usually a bad idea, installing nodejs under c:\program files is wrong as it requires admin rights, you should have installed in another place.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou The error states that it is specifically trying to rename something in 'AppData'. This doesn't have anything to do with program files... I think your assumption is wrong (unless this was unix). I answered what EPERM means in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887306/when-i-wrote-in-my-npm-cache-clean-this-error-is-occurring-npm-err-windows-n