# when i wrote in my "npm cache clean" this error is occurring "npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600 npm ERR! argv

Tags: javascript

when i wrote in my "npm cache clean" this error is occurring "npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600 npm ERR! argv

```
C:\iaAC>npm cache clean
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "cache" "clean"
npm ERR! node v0.12.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.9.1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\AKASH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048

npm ERR! Error: EPERM, rmdir 'C:\Users\AKASH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, rmdir 'C:\Users\AKASH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\AKASH\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\iaAC\npm-debug.log
```

Edit: Cleanup

Comment: Well, did you try running it as root/Administrator as the error message suggested?

Answer (score 8):

As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data e
xtracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use '`npm cache verify`' instead.
If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: Ahh you pasted the console message :).

Answer (score 1):

The error you posted suggests to run 'npm cache clean' as an administrator. You will need to open up a command prompt as Administrator, as shown [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc947813(v=WS.10).aspx).

**Steps:**

1. Click Start, click All Programs, and then click Accessories.
2. Right-click Command prompt, and then click Run as administrator.
3. If the User Account Control dialog box appears, confirm that the
   action it displays is what you want, and then click Continue.

Description of the error code you received (EPERM)

> EPERM: "operation not permitted" simply means the issue is not a matter of granting elevated privileges. Some operations, even with root permissions, aren't allowed by the OS.

Comment: This error is happening on our build servers and local Windows machines and all of them running under Administrator. Issue is random, so this doesn't really address it.

Comment: Same here. This happens only on my build server and only sometimes. It is stupid that its inconsistent. node pains

Answer (score 0):

Over 7 years later in mid-January 2023 using npm 9.3.0 on 64-bit Windows 11 Version 22H2 (OS Build 22621.1105), this ***same error*** `EMFILE too many open files` is happening again.  The ***only thing that works to fix the issue*** is `npm cache clean --force` followed by reinstalling everything that was in the global npm cache using `npm ls -g` to understand how many `npm install -g`  commands to issue.  I would **strongly suggest** running `npm cache verify` before and after each `npm install -g` command.